# Migrating SVN hosts

Tags: svn

We're migrating from an SVN server inside our office to a hosted service.  Currently we're at revision 211 and I'd like to cut off old data (from our previous site, 6+ months old) to avoid the extra storage of images and stuff.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html) command and specify the lowest revision you want to export with the -r parameter.

Answer (score 5):

See [`Migrating a Repository`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) section of `SVN redbook`.